# Pasting in vim on tmux returns this error: E353: Nothing in register *

Tags: vim, tmux

I have Vim inside Tmux. When I copy text using `yy` and paste. I get the following error `E353: Nothing in register *`.

This issue only happens when using Vim 7.4. However, when using Vim outside of Tmux, this issue does not occur.

On a sidenote, this does not happen when using Vim 7.3 (vim version installed by OSX 10.9), inside or outside of Tmux.

In `.vimrc`, I have:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

In `.tmux.conf`, I have:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

Comment: tmux, ssh, vim and vim plugins, can fight each other over control of the system's clipboard and making it one and the same with vim system-registers.  Vim hasn't changed, but tmux and your os clipboard system has.  What worked for me was turning it all off, then making new keybindings to tell vim exactly what to do on a given keystroke.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60200/how-to-copy-data-between-different-instances-of-vim

Answer (score 13):

In my case I just got it fixed by including on `.tmux.conf` the following configuration:

```
set -g default-command 'reattach-to-user-namespace $SHELL --login'
```

Comment: Care to explain the line or link the relevant doc?

Answer (score 7):

Try `"*y` and `"*p`.

If you do that often, put the line below in your `~/.vimrc` to synchronize your system clipboard and Vim's unnamed register:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

See `:help registers` and `:help 'clipboard`.

Comment: I made an edit above. I forgot to mention that I have the set clipboard setting in vimrc

Comment: How did you install Vim?

Comment: I installed Vim 7.4 using Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Actually it seems to only when I start vim on a nerdtrw buffer using `vim .`. Setting again the clipboard to *unnamed* seems to fix the issue (`:set clipboard=unnamed`).

I experienced the same issue. It seems to be a bug in the latest vim versions available via brew (`7.4.430` and `7.4.430_1`).

I did not find any workaround and had to rollback to the previous one that is working fine (`7.4.335`).

To do so:

```
brew rm vim
brew update
cd /usr/local
git checkout 2150e2d2a89f79f3ab58490433e91f7a36ebf150
brew intall vim
git checkout master
brew cleanup
```

If you get a `404` when trying to download vim, edit the formula file in `/usr/local/Library/Formula/vim.rb` and replace:

- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.4.335.orig.tar.gz

by

- http://ftp.vim.org/os/illumos/dyson/apt/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.4.335.orig.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, `E353: Nothing in register *` using Ubuntu 14.04 which has vim version: `2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3` installed from its default PPA repository.

Was working OK with vim version : 7.3

Work around : You can use below options :

1. Use vim -p to open multiple panes. Eg: vim -p file1 file2 and
   copy and paste as necessary. To move between panes, you can use
   ":tabn" or ":tabp"
2. If using Nerdtree plugin with your vim, then
   also you can simply yank and navigate to the destination file and do
   a paste.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in many ways, I can get from the Internet to solve this problem, But finally, the solution is removing your configuration "set clipboard=uname" in your vimrc. 
I'm trying to find why it works...